# startAtLogin does not work with captive runtime, Adobe Air for desktop?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I published my Air project with captive runtime and when I set `startAtLogin=True`, I get a runtime error with code

> #2014.

Is there any solution for `startAtLogin` to work with Air app with captive runtime?

Comment: I have same issue, please let me know what are the possible solutions for this ?
when I test app in release mode.  i get 
#2014
when i test app in Debug mode, i get
#2014: Feature is not available at this time.

in short same issue